# weird gradients appearing in the final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color, color-management

I m trying to render an animation sequence using cycles, but soon as i import my images "tried Tiff,Png and OpenEXR"into after effects i keep getting these wierd lines "Gradients",i want to know what is the best color management settings for a "blender to After Effect workflow".
Settings are in the pictures below:

[image: Weird Lines]

[image: Color management settings]

[image: image Sequence format Tiff]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74809/rendered-image-shows-visible-line-strokes-artefacts

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184495/why-dark-vignette-looks-posterized/184497#184497

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9279/how-to-make-a-dithering-effect-in-blender/9280#9280

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/what-does-dither-do-in-cycles/5800#5800

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183180/does-the-compositor-affect-image-quality

Comment: Thank u so much !